# Covariance Estimation for cauchy noise

Tags: estimation, regularization, cauchy-distribution

Apart from Ledoit wolf shrinkage technique which can be better shrinkage covariance estimators for data with cauchy distribution?
How to calculate optimum shrinkage intensity for data containing cauchy distribution?
I have gone through many shrinkage covariance estimators dealing with normal data or exponential distributions but didnt get for cauchy distribution can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because the Cauchy distribution does not have finite variance, so it would not make sense to estimate variance-covariance in the first place. See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) for the Cauchy distribution or google "Cauchy distribution variance" for more information.